# Where should I post a question about changing color depth of images in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> How do I place a 16bit bit image into Adobe Illustrator without it converting it to 8bit?
>
> I have "Googled" all over the web, but I can't find anything on changing color depth of a AI file to 16bit.

Where should I post this?

Comment: Probably graphicdesign.SE?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good question for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

... And it looks like you [already posted there](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42776/how-do-i-place-a-16bit-bit-image-into-adobe-illustrator-without-it-converting-it) after a comment.